# Commutative algebra: operations on ideals

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals

Let $A$, $B$, $m$ be ideals in a commutative ring $R$. Is $m \cdot (A \cap B) = m \cdot A \cap m \cdot B$?

Let $(A_{\alpha})_{\alpha \in I}$ be a set of ideals. Is $m \cdot \bigcap_I A_{\alpha} = \bigcap_I m \cdot A_{\alpha}$?

I'm trying to prove that in a local Noetherian commutative ring $R$, the intersection $M = \bigcap_n m^n$ of powers of the maximal ideal is $\{0 \}$. My technique of proof was using Nakayama's lemma and the fact that $m \cdot M = M$; proving the non-trivial intersection of the last equality using

\begin{align*} m \cdot M  &= m \cdot \bigcap_n m^n \\
&= \bigcap_1^{\infty} m \cdot m^n \\
&= \bigcap_2^{\infty} m^n \\
&\supseteq M.
\end{align*}

However, I am unsure if I am allowed to use this operation on intersections and products of ideals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, ideal product doesn't usually distribute over intersection.  You'll need something like the Artin-Rees lemma (see [[Stacks 00IN]](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00IN)) to prove that a local Noetherian ring $(R, \mathfrak{m})$ is $\mathfrak{m}$-adically separated.

In your notation, when $m$ is a flat ideal and $A_\alpha$ is a finite set of ideals, then multiplication by $m$ does distribute over the intersection $\bigcap A_\alpha$ (more generally its true if the family $A_\alpha$ is in an appropriate sense compact).  For a reference, see e.g. [[Stacks 0BBY]](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0BBY).

When we don't require that $m$ is flat, this can really fail, even when $m$ is the maximal ideal of a local Noetherian ring.

As an example, consider the ring $k[x,y]$ with $k$ a field and the maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m} = (x,y)$. Let $R = k[x,y]_\mathfrak{m}$.  This is a local Noetherian ring with maximal ideal $(x,y)$.  The ideals $m = (x,y)$, $A = (x), B = (y)$ satisfy the following identies:

$$mA \cap mB = (xy)$$
$$m(A \cap B) = xy(x,y)$$

As a closing remark, let's note the maximal ideal being flat is a big deal.  Observe that in a Noetherian local ring a flat ideal is automatically free (Noetherian implies f.g. flat, and local implies f.g. flat is free), and in general an ideal is free iff it is principally generated by a non-zero divisor.

So in a Noetherian local ring, the maximal ideal is flat iff it is principally generated by a non-zero divisor.  This is a lot to ask for.  It implies that every ideal is a power of $m$.  Hence the ring is either a discrete valuation ring or a field.

Comment: Thank you. I did some research and also found that the Artin-Rees lemma and Krull's intersection theorem should yield me the answer, but this is slightly more general than what I'm trying to prove and we have seen neither in class (nor flatness, nor separatedness). Good to know that this operation in general doesn't hold though.